# How to use GestureDetector with Slider onChange event to stop other events like page scroll in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-slider

**Main Issue:-** Slider onChangeStart not work when used GestureDetector.

```
              GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                  child: Slider(
                    value: value.validate().toInt().toDouble(),
                    min: 1,
                    max: 8,
                    onChanged: (v){},
                    onChangeStart: (v) {
                      value = v.toInt();
                    },
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: By not working , what do you exactly mean ? Are you getting any error ? What you want to accomplish and where are you stuck , can you please be little more descriptive ...

Comment: Did you mean `value = v.toInt();` is not setting the value or setting the state? If yes, what state management are you using? Is it just StatefulWidget?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? onChangeStart event gets triggered, so what exactly is the issue you are facing and what is the datatype definition for the variable value?

Comment: May this help [Slider notifies "onChangeEnd" twice when it is over a InkWell/GestureDetector](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28115)